# Вопрос по анимации на css3 при наведении мыши на элемент

Tags: css3, css-animation

Мне нужно сделать плавное изменение цвета кнопки при наведении на неё мыши. Использовал для этого псевдокласс hover и свойство transition.И когда я навожу мышь на кнопку цвет меняется плавно, но когда мышь покидает пространство кнопки, цвет меняется быстрее,чем при наведении. Как это исправить?Мне нужно чтобы цвет менялся одинаково  плавно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Если свойство `transition` указано только в основном классе, то параметры этого свойства распространяются и на все его псевдоклассы (кнопка 1). То есть также, как если бы свойство было указано и там и там с одинаковыми параметрами (кнопка 2).
- Переходы назначенные для псевдоклассов не распространяются на основной класс. Потому, если для основного класса не задано свойство `transition`, происходит мгновенная смена состояния (кнопка 3). *Скорее всего, так было у Вас.*
- Можно сделать разные переходы для разных состояний, задав различные параметры для основного класса и его псевдоклассов (кнопки 4 и 5).

```css
.btn-1 { transition: all 5s ease; }
.btn-1:hover {  background-color: red; }

.btn-2 { transition: all 5s ease; }
.btn-2:hover { transition: all 5s ease; background-color: gold; }

.btn-3 { }
.btn-3:hover { transition: all 5s ease; background-color: limegreen; }

.btn-4 { transition: all 2s ease; }
.btn-4:hover { transition: all 5s ease; background-color: blue; }

.btn-5 { transition: all 5s ease; }
.btn-5:hover { transition: all 2s ease; background-color: fuchsia; }
```

```html
<button class="btn-1">Кнопка 1</button>
<button class="btn-2">Кнопка 2</button>
<button class="btn-3">Кнопка 3</button>
<button class="btn-4">Кнопка 4</button>
<button class="btn-5">Кнопка 5</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
button {
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!