# Как поправить transition эффект?

Tags: css, jquery, css-animation

Очень нравится выпадающее меню в теме ColorNews ([демо сайт](https://demo.themegrill.com/demos/?theme=ColorNews)). Меню я из этой темы позаимствовал, встроил на свой сайт, однако выяснилась проблема - исчезновение меню при уходе hover неполноценное - меню уже не видно, но если быстро навести мышку обратно туда, где было меню, то оно опять появляется. Жутко некрасиво и неудобно. Понятно, что это из-за кода:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Но если его отрубить - меню теряет всю свою прелесть. В общем, вопрос - как это исправить? css, jquery - неважно. Я хочу, чтобы переставшее быть видимым меню перестало реагировать на hover еще до истечения 0.5s.

Прошу помочь.

https://codepen.io/Flector/pen/GLRQPE

```css
#main-menu {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    border-top: 1px solid #302e2e;    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#main-menu ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-menu ul > li {font-size:12px;
    line-height:1;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #302e2e;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;font-size:14px;
}

#main-menu ul > li li{
    border-right: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a {
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: -11px;
    content: "\e800";
    color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateY(-45%);          
    padding:15px 18px 13px 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "\e801";
}

#main-menu ul > li:hover,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-item,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-ancestor,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-parent {
    background-color: blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #0c0d43;
}

#main-menu ul > li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1.1rem 2rem;
    line-height:1.2;
}

#main-menu ul > li a.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu,
#main-menu ul.children {
    background: #272727 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 270px;
    left: 0;
    top: 120%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 11111;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    float: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li:hover > .sub-menu,
#main-menu ul > li:hover > .children {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu ul,
#main-menu ul.children ul {
    left: 110%;
    top: 0 !important;
}

#main-menu ul.children li,
#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-menu .sub-menu > li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-11482" class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://wptest.ru/" aria-current="page">Главная</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/1">Меню 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-11479"><a href="http://wptest.ru/2/">Под-меню пункт 1</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11478"><a href="http://wptest.ru/3/">Под-меню пункт 2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11480"><a href="http://wptest.ru/4/">Под-меню пункт 3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11451" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/5/">Под-меню пункт 4</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11481"><a href="http://wptest.ru/6/">Под-под меню</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-11477"><a href="http://wptest.ru/7/">Под-меню пункт 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="http://wptest.ru/8/">Меню 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-113"><a href="http://wptest.ru/9/">Меню 4</a></li>
    </ul>    
</nav>
```

я бы хотел что-то типа:

```js
jQuery('#main-menu').hover(function(){

 }, function() {
        jQuery('#main-menu').css("pointer-events","none").delay(500).('#main-menu').css("pointer-events","initial");
})
```

но оно не восстанавливает pointer-events

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939174/265406 Должно помочь.

Comment: Вызывать ховер с помощью js/jq и определять callback функцию.
Покажите код который есть, чтобы была возможность показать наглядно

Comment: Добавил код для примера.

Comment: Никогда! Не используйте `opacity`, именно поэтому и появляется данный эффект. Прозрачность не делает объект недоступным на экране. Что делать? Посмотреть реализацию (примерную), основанную на изменении высоты подменю.

Comment: это мне ничем не помогает. мне нравится это меню - красиво появляется и исчезает. нужно лишь исправить косяк с opacity

Comment: Как вариант можно делать toggleClass и отталкиваясь от класса изменять значения выпадающего списка. Совместно с opacity используется и visibility , в отличии от display: none; он поддается в transition. Как пример: visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-50%); . А при смене класса менять эти значения на : visible, 1, 0% . И да, важно отметить transition, после пропадания меню нужно visibility задать delay после того как отработает opacity и transform. Visibility не нужно анимировать, он лишь убирает видимость объекта на сайте.

Comment: угу - вопрос как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то можно воспользоваться css-свойством pointer-events. При уходе hover с sub-menu задаёте ему значение none, и тогда повторное наведение не сработает. А при hover на родителя возвращаете значение auto:

```js
$('.sub-menu').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
});

$('.menu-item-has-children').mouseover(function(){
  $('.sub-menu').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
});
```

```css
#main-menu {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    border-top: 1px solid #302e2e;    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#main-menu ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-menu ul > li {font-size:12px;
    line-height:1;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #302e2e;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;font-size:14px;
}

#main-menu ul > li li{
    border-right: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a {
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: -11px;
    content: "\e800";
    color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateY(-45%);          
    padding:15px 18px 13px 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "\e801";
}

#main-menu ul > li:hover,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-item,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-ancestor,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-parent {
    background-color: blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #0c0d43;
}

#main-menu ul > li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1.1rem 2rem;
    line-height:1.2;
}

#main-menu ul > li a.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu,
#main-menu ul.children {
    background: #272727 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 270px;
    left: 0;
    top: 120%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 11111;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    float: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li:hover > .sub-menu,
#main-menu ul > li:hover > .children {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu ul,
#main-menu ul.children ul {
    left: 110%;
    top: 0 !important;
}

#main-menu ul.children li,
#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-menu .sub-menu > li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-11482" class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://wptest.ru/" aria-current="page">Главная</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/1">Меню 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-11479"><a href="http://wptest.ru/2/">Под-меню пункт 1</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11478"><a href="http://wptest.ru/3/">Под-меню пункт 2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11480"><a href="http://wptest.ru/4/">Под-меню пункт 3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11451" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/5/">Под-меню пункт 4</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11481"><a href="http://wptest.ru/6/">Под-под меню</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-11477"><a href="http://wptest.ru/7/">Под-меню пункт 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="http://wptest.ru/8/">Меню 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-113"><a href="http://wptest.ru/9/">Меню 4</a></li>
    </ul>    
</nav>
```

Comment: точно, ваш вариант идеальный. спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не стал углубляться в код.
Задача была сделать так же как и на демо-сайте, вот пример, не законченный конечно, ибо копаться дальше в ваших стилях я думаю вы должны сами.

```js
$("#main-menu ul li a").on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
#main-menu {
    background-color: black;
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    border-top: 1px solid #302e2e;    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#main-menu ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-menu ul > li {font-size:12px;
    line-height:1;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #302e2e;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;font-size:14px;
}

#main-menu ul > li li{
    border-right: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a {
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: -11px;
    content: "\e800";
    color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateY(-45%);          
    padding:15px 18px 13px 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    content: "\e801";
}

#main-menu ul > li:hover,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-item,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-ancestor,
#main-menu ul > li.current-menu-parent {
    background-color: blue;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #0c0d43;
}

#main-menu ul > li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1.1rem 2rem;
    line-height:1.2;
}

#main-menu ul > li a.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu,
#main-menu ul.children {
    background: #272727 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 270px;
    left: 0;
    top: 120%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 11111;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #302e2e;
    float: none;
}

#main-menu ul > li a.active ~ .sub-menu,
#main-menu ul > li.active ~ .children {
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

#main-menu ul.sub-menu ul,
#main-menu ul.children ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0 !important;
}

#main-menu ul.children li,
#main-menu ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
}

#main-menu .sub-menu > li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-11482" class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://wptest.ru/" aria-current="page">Главная</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/1">Меню 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-11479"><a href="http://wptest.ru/2/">Под-меню пункт 1</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11478"><a href="http://wptest.ru/3/">Под-меню пункт 2</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11480"><a href="http://wptest.ru/4/">Под-меню пункт 3</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-11451" class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://wptest.ru/5/">Под-меню пункт 4</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11481"><a href="http://wptest.ru/6/">Под-под меню</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-11477"><a href="http://wptest.ru/7/">Под-меню пункт 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-5"><a href="http://wptest.ru/8/">Меню 3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-113"><a href="http://wptest.ru/9/">Меню 4</a></li>
    </ul>    
</nav>
```

Comment: кастрировать меню до click я бы смог и сам. нужен hover.