# У ссылки не меняется цвет при наведении

Tags: css, hover, link

Мне нужно, чтобы ссылка при наведении плавно становилась полупрозрачной, сделать это нужно с помощью  opacity и transition. Я установила свойства, они не работают.

***код css***

```
.header__link {
    color: #2f80ed`;
  }

.header__link:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: opacity 1s linear 2s;
  }
```

Comment: Стили подключены через Nested. Сам .header__link работает, а в состоянии hover нет.

Comment: У вас в color лишний символ ( ` ) в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `transition` определяет переход от одного состояние к другому, в вашем случае должен применяться к селектору который записан без псевдокласса

```css
.header__link {
    color: #2f80ed;
    transition: opacity 1s linear 2s; /* К СЕЛЕКТОРУ БЕЗ ПСЕВДОКЛАССА */
  }

.header__link:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
```

```html
<a class="header__link">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Ольга : ещё по теме - [Вопрос по анимации на css3 при наведении мыши на элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939174/265406)